# auto hide the flash messages in rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, flash

I need to auto fade the flash messages in ruby on rails.

My message code is:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@dashboard_user) do |f| %>
<% if @dashboard_user.errors.any? %>
<ul class="alert alert-danger">
    <% for message_error in @dashboard_user.errors.full_messages %>
    <li>
        <%= message_error %>
    </li>
    <% end %>
</ul>
<% end %>
```

How i auto fade these messages?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This should work for you. You can specify the time span within the brackets. Add this to your Javascript. this is common for all:

```
$(".alert" ).fadeOut(3000);
```

For alert success:

```
 $(".alert-success" ).fadeOut(3000);
```

For alert danger:

```
$(".alert-danger" ).fadeOut(3000);
```

Comment: Is it possible to change fade_out timing for alert success message and alert failure message??

Comment: @shatabdi-mohapatra your solution works for most cases but it doesn't work for alerts generated direcly from application controller, i don't know how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 7):

This one will work with **Turbolinks-3**.

```
$(document).on('page:change', function(){
$(".alert").delay(2000).slideUp(500, function(){
      $(".alert").alert('close');
  });
});
```

**Turbolinks 5:**

```
$(document).on('turbolinks:load', function(){
    $(".alert").delay(2000).slideUp(500, function(){
          $(".alert").alert('close');
      });
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

try:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@dashboard_user) do |f| %>
 <% if @dashboard_user.errors.any? %>
  <span class="error_msgs">
    <ul class="alert alert-danger">
      <% for message_error in @dashboard_user.errors.full_messages %>
        <li>
          <%= message_error %>
        </li>
      <% end %>
    </ul>
  </span>
  <script>
    setTimeout("$('.error_msgs').fadeOut('slow')", 5000)
  </script>
<% end %>
```

this will fade out your flash after 5000ms.

Comment: move the script to file which is common for all views, and use same class for span or whatever you like to fade out.

Answer (score 1):

Place this code in your application layout

```
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="page-wrapper">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
     <% flash.each do |name, msg| %>
       <%= content_tag(:div, msg, :id=>"#{name}", :class `enter code here`=> "alert alert-  info") %>
     <%end%>
    </div>
   </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

And Place this code on the bottom of the application layout

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.setTimeout(function() 
 {
$("#notice").fadeTo(500, 0).slideUp(500, function()
{
$(this).remove();
});
}, 5000);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Added these code in `application.html.erb` its works all over the application.

```
<script>
    setTimeout("$('.error_msgs').fadeOut('slow')", 6000)
    setTimeout("$('.success_msgs').fadeOut('slow')", 3000)
</script>
```

In `view`:

```
<span class="success_msgs"> <% if notice %>
        <p class="alert alert-success">
            <%= notice %>
        </p> <% end %> </span>

<span class="error_msgs"> <% if alert %>
        <p class="alert alert-success">
            <%= alert %>
        </p> <% end %> </span>
```

Answer (score 1):

in layouts shared/flash_messages.html.erb write under script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  setTimeout(function(){
    $('.alert').fadeOut();
   }, 3000);
</script>
```

this works for me. 
note: - if you are declaring fadeout function in application.js file then delete from there.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put it in your application markup, just put some jQuery in a javascript file that can run on every page, and require it in `application.js`

```
$(function() {
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.alert').fadeOut('fast');
  }, 5000);
}
```

This will hide the alert div after 5 seconds